# How can I find changes in momentum/direction of a line graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

Let's say I have a line graph with a $1-\text{minute}$ moving average as pictured below.

I would like to use a script find the $X'd$ positions on the line. The $X's$ represent beginnings of changes in momentum/direction.

Is there an algorithm or mathematical formula(s) to accomplish this? Perhaps a combination of standard deviation and slope?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to make some money on the stock market?  The "change in momentum" theoretically happens at the tops of the peaks and the bottoms of the valleys.  This is where the slope of the graph is momentarily zero before changing direction.  You will need to be a little bit more precise about what you want to find.

Comment: Ahh..."momentarily zero"..."peaks"..."valleys"......that is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I think if you are looking to apply this idea in finance you will soon run into problems regarding the smoothness of the data

Comment: Maybe I can only focus on "major" changes or use a neural network for fuzziness.

Comment: Possibly, I don't know enough to say anything about that though. By the way, if you don't get a good answer here, it might be worth trying on http://quant.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you for the link, Michael! And good point about data smoothness. I had not considered that...I supposed I would have run into that sooner or later :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are looking for points with zero curvature.